# npmjs.org packages on sinopia

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, sinopia

After setting up sinopia, How to install npmjs.org packages on it? Scoped too.

I have tried and succeeded setting up sinopia and even publish my packages.

But did not find any documentation about installing from npmjs.org

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question first you have to understand how sinopia works.

Sinopia is just a private registry that as act as a proxy to cache packages from a remote registry, `npmjs.org`, `yarn` registry or another `sinopia` (or `verdaccio`). In other words, you cannot install packages directly, basically are cached when you perform an `npm install` in your project pointing to a sinopia registry.

```
npm install --registry http://localhost:4873/
```

After such installation looking in the local storage you will find packages downloaded from the uplinks. This process is handled automatically by your private registry and I do not you recommend modifying any metadata otherwise will corrupt the cache.

I wrote documentation for `verdaccio` which is a **sinopia's fork** and backward compatible which might give you an idea how to set up correctly and a brief definition of each part of the private registry.

http://www.verdaccio.org/docs/en/what-is-verdaccio.html

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing this weird issue, where all packages other than the ones start '`@`' are installing via public NPM registry but just the ones starting with `'@'` are are not installing.

For example '**backbone**' or '**jquery**' is installing but `'@angular/cli'` is not installing, please update the sinopia configuration file,
and append the packages:**`'@*/*'`** property with the following entry for '**proxy**',

> ```
> packages:
>   '@*/*':
>     # scoped packages
>     access: $all
>     publish: $authenticated
>     proxy: npmjs
> ```

[Link to above details](https://christianliebel.com/2016/07/configure-sinopia-npm-repository-server-cache-scoped-packages/)